# ¿Como quitar el id de URL y en su lugar colocar un slug en php y htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola estoy creando un pequeño blog en php y realmente no se como usar htaccess para hacer las url amigables. Entonces al momento de ingresar a un post blog tiene la siguiente URL:

```
post?id=119
```

El caso es que por el ID identifico el post y con eso traigo los datos del mismo usando:

```
($_GET['id'])
```

En la pagina del index que es donde estan listados todos los post uso un enlace que lleva hacia los post usando:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $ruta_root . '/post?id=' .$publicaciones['id'];  ?>">Ver Post</a>
```

Ahora lo que quisiera es cambiar esa url por el slug que eh creado para todos los post y quisiera que quede algo parecido a

```
post/titulo-del-post
```

Por htaccess se puede pero no se usarlo o no se si por php se pueda hacer pero aun no los manejo muy bien.

Comment: Se puede, desde forma simple, hasta más avanzadas usando enrutadores, pero eso es un curso. ¿Por qué no lo miras [acá](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php+url+amigables)? Como no hay problemas en la pregunta, probablemente termine cerrada.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: que has intentado en el htaccess???

Comment: ¿Estás usando Wordpress como CMS?

Comment: No uso cms es php puro.

Comment: en htaccess eh agreado esto RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ post?id=$1
pero al ingresar como mi pagina/post.php/1 donde uno seria el id solo consigo una pagina 404 no se realmente como usar htaccess